# How to numerate pictures or diagrams when writing a book or paper?

Tags: numbers, connotations

> This is shown in the diagram 1 / diagram no.1 / diagram number 1. ...
>   The statistics can be seen in diagram 2 / diagram no.2 / diagram
>   number 2.

What is a common way to numerate pictures or diagrams in a paper of a book. I know it might differ based on the journal guideline. But my question is about the most common way.

Comment: Are they usually ***figures*** ? fig. 1, fig. 2 etc? I know I see that a lot in mathematics papers with graphs and diagrams.

Comment: I just pulled 5 books off my shelf at random. Without exception, the graphics were labelled "Figure 1.1" for the first one in chapter 1 (or "Fig. 1.1").